# Laravel is echoing the HTTP header text along the actual payload response

Tags: jquery, reactjs, laravel, http, axios

On the frontend I'm using `React` with `jQuery` as follows:

```
$.ajax({
  url: ...
  method: 'POST',
  contentType: 'application/json',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: (response) => { ... },
  error: (err) => { ... },
});
```

I'm using `Laravel 8.0` on the backend, where on: `app/Http/Controllers/Ajax.php` I have:

```
public function sayHello(Request $request): string
  return response()->json([
      'status' => true,
  ])->setStatusCode(200);
}
```

**My problem is:** the backend is echoing:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache, private
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Tue, 30 Aug 2022 22:03:48 GMT

{"status":true}
```

where you can see it has that header text which messes with the actual data I'm expecting.

Any idea on how to get rid of that header text?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the response type of the backend function.

Just removing: `: string` did the trick.